# Simulating WCF route in WEB API 2

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service

We currently have an old legacy WCF service that I really don't want to maintain but several clients still have access. We currently run all our API services in WEB API 2 in Azure. To enable backward compatibility I was hoping to simulate the WCF routing in WEB API using attribute routing like so:

```
[RoutePrefix("registration.svc")]
public class RegistrationDeprecatedController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Login(CredentialModel creds)
    {...
```

Locally this runs like a dream. As soon as I publish to an Azure AppService however all I get is 404 not found. The specific route in question:

```
/registration.svc/login
```

My suspicion is that IIS hosting has the .svc route file associate to process the requests as a WCF call. An extensive search online failed to find anything on how I can change this association or even confirm if this is the case. Any ideas on how to fix or alternative solutions will be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Found a solution but its not perfect. Found out that it is possible to directly connect to IIS on the AppService instance and change the Handler Mappings. This is not perfect as it would require a manual change when creating a new instance or deployment slot and I would prefer to automate the entire process.

If anyone else would like to do this you can follow a tutorial by [benjamin perkins](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/08/05/configure-remote-iis-administration-for-microsoft-azure-web-sites/). I did have to install an [IIS Manager for remote administration](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41177)  extension on windows 10 however for this to work. I removed all mappings associated to *.svc and the routing is now working.

Comment: Add a handler for that specific path so that you can intercept it before iis can handle it

Answer (score 1):

Final solution was to remove the handlers in the web.config.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="svc-Integrated" />
      <remove name="svc-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="svc-ISAPI-2.0" />
      <remove name="svc-ISAPI-2.0-64" />
      <remove name="svc-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="svc-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      ....
    </handlers>
```

I was able to find the names by connection to IIS on the AppService instance. I was unsure which ones needed to be removed so I removed all that handlers associated with *.svc.

Comment: I've just been searching for exactly this solution, a need to emulate WCF using WebAPI. Your solution of removing the svc handlers in the web.config works perfectly - thanks!